# Ubuntu 13.04 automatic reconnect to hidden wireless network

Tags: wireless, networking, upgrade

I updated form 12.10 to 13.04 and computer will not automatically reconnect to hidden wireless network anymore, have to manually connect every time after booting.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 0):

The "Connect automatically" option is now moved to General tab and is called "Automatically connect to this network when it is available". Are you sure it's checked?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this might be a problem of kernel version>3.5
My machine is a Lenovo Ideapad U310 with:
`$ lspci | grep Network
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2200 (rev c4)`
The module used is iwlwifi. I've had this problem on Arch too, with the "stock" 3.8.x kernel, and sometimes also with a custom built 3.6.9. It was so annoying that I replaced it with 13.04 in hope of any sort of success.

The "automatically connect" option is checked here, and it was also a problem with wicd on Arch.

On ubuntu 12.04 with linux-lts-quantal (kernel ver. 3.5.x) everything just works fine.

Please let us know your hardware configuration.